# Allow specific multiple phones on differing LTE networks

Tags: firewall, truenas

I'd like for me and a few others to access my server just from a web browser without the use of a vpn. But the ip addresses of the devices always change because of LTE networks

What kind of firewall or whitelisting would I need to research in order to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't, easier to just enable authentication (assuming the server uses a protocol that supports authentication) and allow all IP addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell the phones to connect specific mobile networks/towers. Phones firmware use specific algorithms and file (from SIM card) to connect to the most closest and "powerful" tower from home operator or (if not available) from operators in PLMN file.